# Spliting string into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, split

How do I split the string 'data' into an array in javascript?
JSON.parse gives an error

```
let data = "[{'index': '0', 'id': 't0', 'content': 'Hello World'}, {'index': '1', 'id': 'l1', 'content': 'Data'}, {'index': '2', 'id': 'i2', 'content': 'abc'}]";
```

Comment: JSON uses double quotes (not single). Your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the single-quotes with double-quotes so that it's in valid JSON format, and then `JSON.parse` it:

```js
const data = "[{'index': '0', 'id': 't0', 'content': 'Hello World'}, {'index': '1', 'id': 'l1', 'content': 'Data'}, {'index': '2', 'id': 'i2', 'content': 'abc'}]";
const dataArr = JSON.parse(data.replace(/'/g, '"'));
console.log(dataArr);
```

(or, if at all possible, simply fix your `data` string so that it uses double-quotes to begin with)

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is an invalid JSON that's why `JSON.parse` throws you an error.

You can paste the string here at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and it will tell you whats wrong with your JSON string